# About to create a website for mobile devices, unsure of a few things

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile

I'm about to create a mobile version of my website,
I'm used to program to computers only, 
What I do know is that I'll need to keep in mind that devices with different sizes of screens will display the website, therefore I'll need to make the website stretchable and so on,

What I've been wondering though, was what do I do with images?
I'm a person that cares a lot about the quality of images and such in my website, I hate pixelated stuff,

What kind of made me confused was the whole idea of the retina screens,
I developed a few apps for the iPhone, and I had to create images double their size for the retina, but will I need to create large images for my mobile website as well?
I have a strong feeling that I don't, but I thought I'd ask,

Also, I wanted to know what doctype I should use for the website,
and what could help me prevent people from being able to zoom out and make the screen stretch, I used to know this css code that did this,

I would also love to hear some tips for creating such a website from those of you that are already experienced with it,

Thank you very much

Comment: This looks like an overly broad and vague question, which is more about design than about programming. There are surely different kinds of images that require different treatment (and techniques), so an answer would be rather long—and a tutorial rather than a specific answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as doctype you can use two `<!DOCTYPE>`s and are as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

----OR----

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

To stop it from stretching you could also use a set viewport, this I have used in many mobile websites (Normally multiples of 320 for iOS)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640" />
```

But ultimately you should also look into [jQuery Mobile Framework](http://jquerymobile.com/) as well.

For most images I am using, I will export in Photoshop at 30% quality and at the size I my require for the site. with using a set viewport, you really don't have to worry about the size.

Alternatively you could use `CSS3` media screen size to format your css (can also be formated for portrait and landscape)

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, but what about the images that I'll be using? I wanted to design buttons and such, and use them instead of the standard ones, how will I know in what size I need to save them in?

Comment: Only best way is to trial and error, any time I create a mobile site I use at least 4 different devices to test on.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! :), I only have two devices that I can try it on hehe, an android tablet and an iPhone 4, I have a feeling that it'll be enough though

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a mobile framework like [jQuery mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com).  It will make all these problems much easier to solve.
For displaying images specifically, you might want to use a plugin such as [photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/)

Comment: I have tried jQuery mobile and was quite disappointed, it surely is nice and makes the mobile website look like an actual app, but from my experience it's still too bugged for my taste, it held my browser more than once, the transition effects were also slow at times, I'm just not so interested in using this at the moment, thanks though :)

Comment: Can I ask when you tried jqm?  Version 1.0 was as you described, very buggy and slow.  However subsequent versions are much faster and cleaner.  You certainly do pay a price for the convenience of using the framework, that's for sure, but I feel like as long as you're not using a Touch 1.0 the performance is OK.  What you say about the transitions is true, I think I had to just turn them off, as they were a little clunky.

Comment: Also if you use photoswipe, you don't have to worry as much about image sizes, as the plugin handles all the re-sizing for you.  In their demos they use about 400x500 px images and they look very good to me.

Comment: Oh I tried it about 5 months ago, then I just put the whole mobile version of my site on hold, I will definitely give it another shot though, and I didn't hear about photoswipe, I'll try that as well :)